# Why are Hubble's magnetorquers angled?

Tags: artificial-satellite, attitude, magnetic-field, magnetorquer

Watching a [video](https://youtu.be/qEZI9DxIQss?t=426) on how Hubble attitude control works I saw one portion on magnetorquers. It has four for redundancy but they are angled in a way that looks awkward from a packaging viewpoint, so what is the purpose for the way they are installed? I understand they need to be orthogonal, but there seem to be easier ways to do that than this.

[image]

Comment: slightly related: [What were the relative orientations of the Hubble Space Telescope's three star cameras, six rate gyros and four reaction wheels optimized for exactly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42061) and [Hubble's one-gyro mode; how does it work for attitude control, stabilization, and slewing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31180)